# App store submission issue with sharing extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My application has got sharing extension feature. Everything worked fine while making adhoc build. While submitting my application to app store i am getting

**ERROR ITMS-9000:"Invalid info.plist key. The key 'NSExtensionPointName' in bundle appname.app/Plugins/appnameShare.appex is invalid."**

**ERROR ITMS-9000:"Invalid info.plist key. The key 'NSExtensionPointVersion' in bundle appname.app/Plugins/appnameShare.appex is invalid."**

Comment: If you don't show the Info.plist, no one will be able to assist.

Comment: Not true, not sure why there are down votes here. The question explains a real and confusing issue, and it presents enough info to answer the question. We're talking about an App Extension, and we're talking about 2 specific keys that are flagged upon attempt to submit to the App Store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSExtensionPointName` and `NSExtensionPointVersion` have been deprecated. This happened sometime between the first Xcode 6 beta and the Xcode 6 GM.

Simply remove them from your extension's plist and submission should work. `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` remains required, along with a few others.

*Edit*

Docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html)